# How do I get a user to sign in with Google to access a Deployed GAS Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-signin

I have a Google App Script Web App. I want to make it compulsory to enter with Google account credentials. I would like each new request to be 'approved' by an admin user by emailing the account request to the admin user then allowing the user access the Web App only after the admin user has approved the request. I also want to reference the session user based on the Google Credentials.

I went to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) and followed the `CONFIGURE PROJECT` window, I could not enter the Web App's URL because `Invalid Origin: URIs must not contain a path or end with "/".`

[This](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxsDQyIpFJ4fF6qq1mq-4t7VGxZS7pHYaJwo6h1tKeK0_I/exec) is the URL for my web app.

This web app is meant to be used by a maximum of 5 people.

```
function doGet(){
   //Basic for now: 
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mainhtml');
}
```

How to present the user with a `Sign in with Google` button then send that request to an admin with `GmailApp.sendEmail('admin@email.com', 'Request to join', )`

Then allow the user to access the site once the admin user has accepted the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide is used to integrate Google Auth to a "non google" web site. To force user to be authentified (google way), simply deploy your GAS webapp with "Who has access to the app: **anyone**". Take care to not select "anyone, even anonymous" which allow access to user not connected to Google...

Then to satisfy the "need for check by admin", i see no other way that coding it by yourself :

```
function doGet(){
   //Control user
   var contentToDisplay;
   if(userIsOk()) { contentToDisplay = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mainhtml');
   } else { 
      sendRequestToAdmin();
      contentToDisplay = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forbiddenhtml'); }
   return contentToDisplay;
}
```

Then you can imagine what you want in "sendRequestToAdmin()" and "userIsOk()". For example you could search for the user email in a spreadsheet into which are listed all the allowed users.